# How to use JWT with Koding's Kite Library

Tags: go, jwt, microservices, kite

I'm trying to implement a REST API based on microservices, and the technical stack I selected for my proof of concept is:

- Go as the programming language
- Koding's Kite as the microservice library
- Labstack's Echo as the HTTP framework to implement the API Gateway

My idea is to implement an authentication microservice that returns a JWT and a dummy test microservice that requires authentication.

Reading some articles here and there, I thought authentication was a deal of the API Gateway and microservices didn't care about security, but looking at the Kite API it looks like I was wrong.

Unfortunately Kite's documentation doesn't contain much info on how to use kites (services) securely.

Given I know how to deal with JWT in a traditional REST API, could someone explain me how to use JWT with Kite?